# Why does xlsxwriter export the data in my database from Django admin to Excel in the wrong order?

Tags: django, excel, export, xlsxwriter

I am using xlsxwriter to export the contents of my database from Django admin to an Excel file. The headers in the Excel file are supposed to be my model field names, followed by the rows of data from my db. I've gotten the export process to work, however when I open the downloaded Excel file it shows all the columns/data from my database in a seemingly random order. They do not appear in the same order as the fields as seen in Django admin. In Django admin the info displays in the proper order of a table,

Column A - Column B - Column C - Column D - Column E - etc.

whereas in my exported Excel file I am seeing it all scrambled up,

Column B - Column E - Column A - Column D - Column C - etc.

Here is my code. I don't understand why it wouldn't be exporting the column names and data in the right order. Any help appreciated!

```
def dump_attorneys_to_xlsx(request):
    if request.GET.get('export'):
        output = BytesIO()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Summary')

        attorneys = Attorney.objects.all().values()
        # Write header
        worksheet.write_row(0, 0, attorneys[0].keys())
        # Write data
        for row_index, row_dict in enumerate(attorneys, start=1):
            worksheet.write_row(row_index, 0, row_dict.values())
        workbook.close()

        output.seek(0)

        response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=summary.xlsx'

        return response
    else:
        return render("change_list.html",
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request),
                      template_name='change_list.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

`values()` returns rows as a list of dictionaries. In Python dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Ahhh, this explains it! Is there a way to sort the dictionaries so that they match the order of the Django model's fields?